# How to change row title position using Eureka framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, eureka-forms

It's posible to change the row title position using Eureka framework?.
Row title's default position is at center of the textfield, and I need set it at top of textfield

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: which row type are you using?

Comment: I need too use many types of rows, for example: TextRow, DateInlineRow, PickerInlineRow, etc. When the row title is visible, it should be above from the textfield, as shown in the second picture.

Comment: you need all your rows without any left margin is that what you need?

Comment: I have updated the question and image, thanks

Comment: @MartinRegas  I want to do the same.  Did you ever figure it out?